# Special case of confirmatory factor analysis

Tags: factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor

I remember that I read an article about factor analysis where they assume that each item loads on one and only one latent factor. For example, in the following factor loading matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\\lambda_2&0\\\lambda_3&0\\0&\lambda_4\\0&\lambda_4\\0&\lambda_5\\0&\lambda_6\\0&\lambda_7\\\end{pmatrix},$$
the first three items load on the first latent factor while the last four load on the second factor.

In that article, the author calls this kind of the factor analysis exercise by a special name. However, I do not remember the title nor the name of this kind.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you referring to "simple structure"?

Comment: @jsakaluk: You help me a lot with this term. I am looking for a paper taking about it to take it as a reference for my paper.

Comment: confirmatory factor analysis?